# starting pry shell

Tags: ruby, pry

I have downloaded the zip package for windows of `pry` an alternative for `irb` shell from [github](https://github.com/pry/pry/downloads). I have unzipped the package.

How do i start the pry shell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the zip package, Pry is just a regular gem. In a terminal -- or whatever Windows calls those nowadays -- do the following (assuming you don't need something like `sudo` for Ruby on Windows):

```
gem install pry pry-doc
```

Done. Now start it with `pry`.

Comment: Github repos always offer you the chance to download the source code of the repo as a zip or tarball.

Comment: ['I' tried this,but i am unable to install using the command you mentioned. I am using linux](http://i46.tinypic.com/34guki9.png)

Comment: @SuhailGupta Did you even try to google for that mistake? SO for example is full with answers for that problem... If you use rvm, `rvm pkg install zlib` will help.